# inject infinispan cache into wildfly 8.0.0.Final

Tags: java, jboss, infinispan, wildfly-8

I'm trying to use infinispan (6.0) from my application deployed in wildfly 8.0.0.Final in standalone configuration (jdk 1.7) but I have some problems with injection.
Starting from [this post](https://community.jboss.org/thread/237916) and searching on google I had this sistuation:

In standalone.xml

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:2.0">
            ...
            <cache-container name="my-cache" default-cache="my-cache-default">
                <local-cache name="my-cache-default">
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
```

And

```
public class CacheManager {

    @Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/container/my-cache")
    private EmbeddedCacheManager myCacheManager;

    public Cache<String, String> getCache() {
        return myCacheManager.getCache();
    }
}
```

Finally in the pom.xml

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.ejb.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
                ...
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Dependencies>org.infinispan.commons export</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

that produces in my MANIFEST.MF

```
Dependencies: org.infinispan.commons export
```

When i use the getCache() method i have java.lang.NullPointerException because the myCacheManager attribute is null.
Looking in the JNDI Bindings tab in the administration console I noticed that, while there are many other resources defined by me like datasources, there's no resource corresponding to "java:jboss/infinispan/container/my-cache" (that I supposed to be the default path).
I also tryed to specify the jndi name in the cache container definition, with the same results.

Where I am wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try the JBoss AS quickstart in https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/tree/master/jboss-as7 ? It should work, as is, on Wildfly 8. Maybe you want to give it a go to that and then see if it works for you first?

Comment: @Galder, It works...I made some change in their code and I noticed that in the "@PostConstruct" of the Resource Singleton the container field is null, just like me. In the Controller bean cache is correctly injected. However my scenario is different. I don't use jsf. I need a singleton object that globally contains the cache. Maybe my approach is wrong?

Comment: I'm not an expert in that area, but AFAIK, injection works on code that is processed somehow by the server, so, that needs to be CDI, JSF, EJB...etc code. Injection does not work in standard java classes deployed on AS that do not use any of these components

Comment: @Galder I think you're right. I tried to inject the "@Resource" in a "@Singleton" annotated class and it works. Unfortunatly it is a bit inconvenient for me because it implies I have to use my CacheManager like an EJB, so inject in another EJB, etc. I'm afraid it is a recursive problem. I will evaluate whether to use infinispan in the classic way. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: That's the big problem of CDI IMO. Although the idea is good, it's too tighly coupled with all the EE baggage :|. I have other suggestions but it all depends on your environment, the requirements you have...etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`@Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/container/my-cache")
 private CacheContainer container;`

instead of below

`@Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/container/my-cache")
 private EmbeddedCacheManager myCacheManager;`

This will give your cache container and also add dependencies org.infinispan export in META-INF